# What does 'personal' mean?

Tags: metaphysics

I'm struggling with the meaning of 'personal' when one refers to man being personal. I've heard that 'personal' refers to those aspects that distinguish man from non-man, but I find that answer unsatisfactory. Wearing clothes certainly doesn't form part of our being personal?

Comment: See [Personal Identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-personal/) for references.

Comment: But in human society clothes is a way to differenetiate a group of humans from other groups, and for sure animal do not wear clotehs. Thus, you mast distinguish between *social* identity (humans vs non-humans and human group vs human group) and *personal* (i.e. individual) identity.

Comment: Without context it's nearly impossible to answer this.

Comment: The concept of a person has often been examined, and attracted a variety of answers. I am disinclined to refuse the question even as it stands.

Comment: @LookingForJoanna. Are you asking 'What is a person ?', 'How does one distinguish persons from non-persons ?'

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas. Yes, I think that might be another way of stating my question. What distinguishes man from non-man?